# $\lim_{n \to \infty }\int_{0}^{n}\frac{n \cdot e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{x^4+n^2}dx=$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\int_{0}^{n}\frac{n \cdot e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{x^4+n^2}dx=?$$

I am allowed to used all the classical techniques of calculus, and this was a question from measure theory when we were studying theorem of dominated convergence, monotonic convergence. Usually I would prove that some $f_n(x)$ is rising and then the limit of $f_n(x)$, but here for instance if I take $f_n(x)=\frac{n \cdot e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{x^4+n^2}\lambda_{[0,n]}(x)$, $\lambda_{[0,n]}(x)$ is obviously rising, but is $\frac{n \cdot e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{x^4+n^2}?$ If so, how do I prove this? Can this question be done using theorem of dominated convergence?

Trying $x=n \cdot y$ I get: $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\int_{0}^{n}\frac{n \cdot e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{x^4+n^2}dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^y}{n^2y^4+1}dy$$ I tried to find a dominated function with this, it didn't work.

Comment: Substituting $x = n\cdot y$ looks promising.

Comment: No, I mean $x = n\cdot y$, or, if you prefer, $y = \frac{x}{n}$.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: How about $e^y$ for a dominating function? Or $\frac{e^y}{1+y^4}$? Also note that the sequence is monotonic.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this. :)

Comment: Do you know, by any chance where I can come across more exercises for these types of assignments? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my try.

Let: $f_n (y) = \frac{e^y}{n^2y^4+1} \mathbb I_{[0,1]}$
, where $\mathbb I$ is indicator function. We have: $f_n(y) \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$.

For integrability and domination condition, for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $|f_n(y)| \leq \frac{e^y}{y^4+1} \mathbb I_{[0,1]} \leq e^y \mathbb I_{[0,1]}$. This function is integrable on $\mathbb R$, thus $f_n(x)$ is also integrable on $\mathbb R$.

Now all conditions of the theorem of dominated convergence satisfy. So,
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} f_n (y)dy = \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(y)dy = 0$$